# Understanding modules in Node.js

Tags: node.js

I've just started reading articles about Node.js and there is one thing, which I find very difficult to understand, so thought you guys might help! :)

In particular,

```
var PI = Math.PI;

exports.area = function (r) {
  return PI * r * r;
};

exports.circumference = function (r) {
  return 2 * PI * r;
};
```

And the explanation for it is:

> This code creates a PI variable that can only be accessed by code
>   contained within the module; it is not accessible outside of the
>   module. Next, two functions are created on the exports object. These
>   functions are accessible outside of the module because they are
>   defined on the exports object. As a result, PI is completely protected
>   from outside interference. Therefore, you can rest assured that area()
>   and circumference() will always behave as they should (as long as a
>   value is supplied for the r parameter).

Now, what I find very confusing is what they mean by "within the module" and "outside of the module". What I have understood so far is that modules essentially are what we refer to as encapsulation, right?

With that in mind, when they mention:

> This code creates a PI variable that can only be accessed by code
>   contained within the module; it is not accessible outside of the
>   module.

..do they mean that PI plays the role of what is known as a Global variable?
Also, if PI is a global variable, then why is it :

> PI is completely protected
>
> > from outside interference.

Thanks!

Comment: context: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/nodejs-for-beginners--net-26314

Comment: You're close! In fact, you're creating a *local* variable (i.e. your variable `PI` is local to this module) rather than a global one. So, the `PI` variable that you create, unlike `Math.PI` (which is an attribute on the global `Math` variable), cannot be referenced or changed by other modules.

Comment: Modules in node correspond to files, so "within this module" is just "in this file".

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!
In a nutshell, module is what we know as a class and upon a creation of a variable, it is always local to the class and global to other modules only when an attribute of another global variable? @Derek Peterson

Answer (score 0):

When you say `module.exports`, you're making those variables/functions available to any files that do a `require` on your code file. The reason why `PI` is not available to outside interference is because you aren't assigning `PI` to the `module.exports` object as such:

`module.exports.PI = PI;`

So to take this one step further, if your code was in a file named `geometry.js` and you had another file named `circle.js` in the same directory. `circle.js` can access both `circumference` & `area` by requiring `geometry.js` in `circle.js` as such:

```
// circle.js
var geometry = require('geometry.js');

console.log(geometry.area(2));
console.log(geometry.circumference(2));
```

Essentially, if a variable isn't added to the `module.exports` object it is local to the file, if it is added to the `module.exports` object it is available to any other code that implements your code in a `require` statement.

Here is a great explanation of modules along with examples in [Mixu's Node Book](http://book.mixu.net/node/ch8.html)

> #### Excerpt from Mixu's Node Book Chapter 8
>
> Modules are crucial to building applications in Node, as they allow you to include external libraries, such as database access libraries - and they help in organizing your code into separate parts with limited responsibilities. You should try to identify reusable parts in your own code and turn them into separate modules to reduce the amount of code per file and to make it easier to read and maintain your code.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer to that is revealed in the opening paragraph that contains the code you posted

> `var myModule = require('./myModule.js');`
>
> Modules are encapsulated pieces of code. The code within a module is mostly private - meaning that the functions and variables defined within them are only accessible from the inside of the module. You can, however, expose functions and/or variables to be used outside of the module.

That code you posted would be `myModule`. `PI` would be inside of that module, and only accessible from inside the module.

You can do `myModule.area()` from outside the module, after first doing the first line where you `require` it. But you cannot do `myModule.PI`, because it is local to that module, and thus, inaccessible unless you write something to `export` it.